# How to check on button click is the radio button checked angular2/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

In my html :

```
<input #myRadio type="radio" name="category" id="work-time" />


<button (click)="myClick(myRadio)">save</button>
```

In my component:

```
myClick(_myRadio:HTMLElement)
{

}
```

I have tried to save the result in a boolean type variable, but there is no attribute isChecked or Value, so I am stuck in this.

How to check if the radio button is checked on the button click by the user?

Comment: you can still get the element like javascript as https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_value.asp here. But I do not think it would be the best practice.

Comment: ye, I know. I managed to do it with js, but it's now allowed to do it with js

Comment: You can pass the event inside your click and check what's in it as (click)="myClick($event)" and in your function get myClick(event: any) and print it to see what's passed

Comment: What i do is a suggestion, that does not solve the problem issued above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ngModel`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" [(ngModel)]="category" />
<button (click)="myClick()">save</button>
```

`NgModel` binds the checkbox value (if checked `true` otherwise `false`) to a class property `category`. The method called by button click `myClick()` can then use the property:

```
myClick() {
  // do stuff with this.category;
}
```

If you'd prefer to **not** import the forms module, you can use property and event bindings on the input to accomplish the same result:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" [checked]="category" (click)="category = !category" />
<button (click)="myClick()">save</button>
```

Comment: if the radio is checked and user clicks save  I just need to set a boolean variable to be true so I can go in my if statement block.

Comment: It sounds like the input type we're looking for is checkbox, it provides a boolean value: checked or not-checked. I'll update my answer.